# Input tag is not selecting multiple images in some devices

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, input

I have created a website where users can upload the questions with images. For that purpose I am using input tag with "multiple" attribute to select multiple images and upload it into the database using PHP. But in some devices or may be browsers it is not selecting multiple images or storing it in the database. In those devices it is storing only single image.
I am providing my input tag code. If you need I can provide the full page code with database connection code.

Can you please tell me the solution.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/png , image/jpeg" multiple id="quesImgSelect" onchange="quesPreview()" class="imgBtn" name="quesDoc[]">
```

Tried to upload multiple images but it is not working in some devices.

Full code of my page is here ......

````
session_start();
//include "config.php";

?>
<!-- Uploading code starts -->

<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  // print_r("expression");exit()
if (empty($_FILES['ansDoc']['name'][0])) {

$ansImgText = "no" ;
}else{
   
$ansImgText = "yes" ; 
  
  };


  if (empty($_FILES['quesDoc']['name'][0])) {

    $quesImgText = "no" ;
    }else{
       
    $quesImgText = "yes" ; 
      
      };


  $userId = $_SESSION['id'];

$question ="no" ;
$exam =$_GET['exam'] ;
$year =$_GET['year'] ;
$ansText =(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['ansText'])) ;
$quesText =(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['quesText'])) ;
$subject =(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['sub'])) ;
$lang =(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lang'])) ;
if($_POST['lang'] == ""){
    $topic ="no" ;
}else{
    $topic =(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['topic'])) ;
}

$approval ="no" ;
$solution ="no" ;
$paperId =$_GET['id'] ;

//echo $paperId.$year;
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date=date("y-m-d");

$sql="INSERT INTO `questions` (`question`, `userId`, `date`, `subject`, `lang`, `topic`, `approval`, `solution`, `exam`, `year`, `paperId`,`quesImg`,`ansImg`) VALUES    
('{$quesText}', '{$userId}', '{$date}','{$subject}','{$lang}', '{$topic}','{$approval}','{$ansText}','{$exam}','{$year}','{$paperId}','{$quesImgText}','{$ansImgText}')";
 
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die("result failed1");

  
 $idd= $conn->insert_id; 

//echo $idd;

// print_r($_FILES['quesDoc']);exit();

foreach($_FILES['quesDoc']['name'] as $key=>$val){
    
$filename = rand().".jpg";
// 3,000,000
// print_r($_FILES['quesDoc']['size'][$key]);exit();
$file_size = $_FILES['quesDoc']['size'][$key];
//if($file_size < 3000000){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['quesDoc']['tmp_name'][$key],"quesImg/".$filename);

$sql2="INSERT INTO `quesimg` (`qId`, `image`,`paperId`) VALUES ('{$idd}','{$filename}','{$paperId}')";

$result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2) or die("result failed2");
//}
   // echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);

//echo "added";
}

//if (!empty($_FILES['ansDoc']['name'][0])) {

foreach($_FILES['ansDoc']['name'] as $key=>$val){
    
    $filename2 = rand().".jpg";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ansDoc']['tmp_name'][$key],"ansImg/".$filename2);
    
    $sql3="INSERT INTO `solutionimg` (`qId`, `image`,`paperId`) VALUES ('{$idd}','{$filename2}','{$paperId}')";
    
    $result3=mysqli_query($conn,$sql3) or die("result failed3");
    
       // echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    
   // echo "added";

  //  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM `question_paper` WHERE `id` = $paperId";
$result4=mysqli_query($conn,$sql4) or die("result failed4");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result4)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)){
       $total = $row['total'] ;
       $newTotal = $total + 1;
        
       // echo $newRented;
    $sql5="UPDATE `question_paper` SET `total` = $newTotal  WHERE `question_paper`.`id` = $paperId";

   
    $result5=mysqli_query($conn,$sql5) or die("result failed5"); 
          
   // echo "updated";
    }


    
    
}


$sql6 = "SELECT * FROM `ZZZ_teacherProfile` WHERE `id` = $userId";
$result6=mysqli_query($conn,$sql6) or die("result failed");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result6)>0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6)){
       $total = $row['ques'] ;
       $newTotal = $total + 1;
        
       // echo $newRented;
    $sql7="UPDATE `ZZZ_teacherProfile` SET `ques` = $newTotal  WHERE `ZZZ_teacherProfile`.`id` = $userId";

   
    $result7=mysqli_query($conn,$sql7) or die("result failed6"); 
          
   // echo "updated";
    }


    
    
}




    echo "<script>";
    echo  "alert('Question added successfully.')";
      echo  "</script>";

    }


}
?>

<!-- Uploading code ends -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add question</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="addQuestionPage.css">

    
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">


<div id="backBtnContainer">
    <a href="adminPaperDetailPage.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">Back</a>
</div>
        
        <form  action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <label for="language">Select language</label>

        <select name="lang" id="language">
<option value="english">English</option>
    <option value="hindi">Hindi</option>

</select>

<label for="subjectsDropdown">Select subject</label>
  <select id="subjectsDropdown" onchange="loadTopics()" name="sub">

  <?php
    include "config.php";
  
       $sql="SELECT * FROM `$db`.`ZZ_subject` ORDER BY `name` ASC";
       $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               $data['id']=$row['0'];
            $data['subject']= $row['1'];
          
            ?>
         
        <option value="<?php   echo $row['name'];  ?>"> <?php   echo $row['name'];  ?></option>

  <?php
           }

          
        }else{ 
            echo "No category added";

        }
        ?>
 
</select>
<label for="topicsDropdown">Select topic</label>

<!-- Second Dropdown (Topics) -->
<select id="topicsDropdown" name="topic">
 
</select>


<textarea rows="10"  placeholder="Enter question" class="inputBox" id="quesText" name="quesText"></textarea>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple id="quesImgSelect" onchange="quesPreview()" class="imgBtn" name="quesDoc[]">
<label for="quesImgSelect" class="ImgLabel"> <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload question image Should be less than 3mb </label>
<p id="quesImgCount" >No file choosen</p>
<div id="quesImage" class="imgDiv"></div>

<textarea rows="10" cols="60" placeholder="Enter answer" class="inputBox" id="answerText" name="ansText"></textarea>
<input type="file" accept="image/png , image/jpeg" multiple="multiple" id="ansImageSelect" class="imgBtn" onchange="ansPreview()" name="ansDoc[]">
<label for="ansImageSelect" class="ImgLabel"> <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i> Upload answer image Should be less than 3mb</label>

<p id="ansImgCount" >No file choosen</p>
<div id="ansImage" class="imgDiv"></div>

<input type="submit" value="SAVE" id="submit" name="submit">



</form>



<script>
function loadTopics() {
  // Get the selected subject from the first dropdown
  let selectedSubject = document.getElementById("subjectsDropdown").value;

  // Get the second dropdown element
  let topicsDropdown = document.getElementById("topicsDropdown");

  // Clear the existing options in the second dropdown
  topicsDropdown.innerHTML ;

  // Use AJAX to fetch topics for the selected subject from the database
  // You can use any AJAX library like jQuery or fetch API
  fetch('G_getTopic.php?subject_id=' + selectedSubject)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        topicsDropdown.innerHTML = '';
      // Check if there are topics available for the selected subject
      if (data.length > 0) {
        data.forEach(topic => {
          addTopicOption(topic.topic_name, topic.topic_name);
        });
      } else {
        addTopicOption('no', 'No topic added');
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching topics: ', error);
    });
}

// Helper function to add options to the second dropdown
function addTopicOption(value, text) {
  let topicsDropdown = document.getElementById("topicsDropdown");
  let option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = value;
  option.text = text;
  topicsDropdown.appendChild(option);
}


//Images code ---------------------------------------------------------------


let quesInput = document.getElementById("quesImgSelect");
let ansInput = document.getElementById("ansImageSelect");

let quesCountView = document.getElementById("quesImgCount");
let ansCountView = document.getElementById("ansImgCount");

let quesImageDiv = document.getElementById("quesImage");
let ansImageDiv = document.getElementById("ansImage");


function quesPreview(){
    quesCountView.textContent = `${quesInput.files.length} Files selected`;

    for(i of quesInput.files){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let figure = document.createElement("figure");
        let figCap = document.createElement("figCaption");

        figCap.innerText = i.name;
        figure.appendChild(figCap);
        reader.onload=()=>{
            let img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src",reader.result);
            figure.insertBefore(img,figCap);
        }
        quesImageDiv.appendChild(figure);
        reader.readAsDataURL(i);
    }
}


function ansPreview(){
    ansCountView.textContent = `${ansInput.files.length} Files selected`;

    for(i of ansInput.files){
        let reader = new FileReader();
        let figure = document.createElement("figure");
        let figCap = document.createElement("figCaption");

        figCap.innerText = i.name;
        figure.appendChild(figCap);
        reader.onload=()=>{
            let img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src",reader.result);
            figure.insertBefore(img,figCap);
        }
        ansImageDiv.appendChild(figure);
        reader.readAsDataURL(i);
    }
}
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: It would make sense to include enough code to be able to reproduce the problem (but no more than that!), and also some description of which devices/browsers your testing has identified as consistently having a problem.

Comment: Can you rather write `multiple="multiple"` ?

Comment: I have tried that but still it is not working

Comment: @nice_dev `multiple` [is a boolean attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/multiple) so giving it a text value wouldn't make any sense. (In the major browsers AFAIK it  wouldn't stop it from working, but it's still nonsensical). Its presence in the tag, without an explicit value set, [counts as setting it to `true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean/HTML).

Comment: @ADyson Fair but some long time ago, somewhere I had read a doc which said to follow this syntax for IE browsers.

Comment: @nice_dev perhaps so, but thankfully those wild west days of  complete disregard for the specs are long gone. If the OP is still trying to make this work in I.E., that would, in 2023 be a very unusual situation that they need to mention. (In any case, as I said above, they need to tell us more info about the observations they've  made of where/when this appears to be failing. :-)

Comment: in default browsers of mobile devices it is failing and sometimes on opera also it is failing .. It is note specific to any browser as on my laptop opera browser it is working but on opera browser present on my freinds's laptop it is not working ...

Comment: on vivo browser it is not working

Comment: Although I am not sure if it is the problem of browser or something else ?

Comment: I am  providing you the full code of my page

Comment: `the full code of my page`...is that a [mre] of the issue, or is any of it irrelevant? (i.e. if you removed some parts of the code, we would still experience the problem). Please make sure you provide _only_ what is necessary to demonstrate the problem, without anything which would  distract us or make it take longer to understand the situation.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data. mysqli_real_escape_string is obsolete and doesn't prevent everything

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Anyway I don't see anything in the HTML or PHP code which would cause any issue with uploading multiple files. More likely, either the specific browsers you mentioned don't  support multiple uploads from one input element, or you didn't select the files properly and ensure multiple selections were in place before uploading. If possible, use developer tools in each affected browser to see what is actually sent to the server in the post request.